# How to put Title on Top of Image in welcome/Finish Page NSIS

Tags: nsis

I have created an Installer, which has Image on Welcome/Finish page as Full Screen. 
To Achieve Full Screen of the image, I have done,

!define MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP "1.bmp"

!define MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP_NOSTRETCH

But the Title and MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TEXT is being hidden beyond the image.

How to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you have done something out of the ordinary with the UI design then you need to post a fully working example script...

Answer (score 0):

Use **SetWindowPos()** function with HWND_BOTTOM/TOP flags (from WindowWinAPI function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to set position of texts and picture.

Move picture to the back and texts to foreground.

To achieve this in NSIS without writing a C/C++ plug-in use *SendMessage*.

Comment: Thanks for responses. I found some answer on this link:
     http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=310323